# Powershell not showing values of gulp tasks

Tags: node.js, powershell, command-line, gulp

My gulp tasks are not showing any values in Power Shell.

Everything is working, it's just a display problem. 
It happens for all different gulp plugins/tasks.

Down below you can see the screenshot of the actual problem.  The lines with `Css minified:`, `Css prefixed:`, `Finished 'cass_app' after` should end with some duration.

The issue is not linked to any of the plugins or tasks (it also happens with browser-sync not displaying local ports)...

[image: power shell log]

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you elaborate the problem? What is the script/what are you doing? And with the picture, is that what you're trying to achieve or that's the current problem (means, something is missing from the outputs). If so, what are they? As to my knowledge, you don't really miss any output there...

Comment: @LamLe Thanx for the input, I've edited the question. Let me know if you believe it still lacks some information. I'm not sure describing the actual gulp tasks would be useful. The exact same tasks were displaying well on another machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your edit, I can see it now :D damn little numbers.

I have taken a look at the [source code](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli)? I think gulp CLI used ANSI color characters which are not supported fully by Powershell.

Other workarounds I know for now:

- Run with `no-color` flag: `gulp <task_name> --no-color`. This looks a bit dull.
- If it's possible, use cmd instead. The outputs are fine, and you can keep the colors.
- Or, from PS, you can delegate the task to cmd then print the output to PS console:

  ```
  $output = Invoke-Expression "gulp"
  $output
  ```

There are some discussions on this topic:

- [PowerShell not displaying Unix colors, SuperUser StackExchange question](https://superuser.com/questions/85058/powershell-not-displaying-unix-colors)
- [Enable ANSI color support in Windows console, discussion on GitHub of dart-lang](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28614)
- [Help with 256 color support on Windows](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/1968)

Comment: Thank you very much, i ended up simply using cmd instead of PS.

Comment: The colors work fine in Visual Studio Code's PowerShell terminal.  I was having the same issue when running SharePoint web parts.  Also ConEmu shows the text properly too.